# Can I avoid copies when returning multiple values, while keeping my return type?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, copy-elision, nrvo, stdmove

If we write the following function:

```
auto foo() {
    Foo foo { /* ... */ };
    do_stuff(foo);
    return foo;
}
```

then [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) should kick in, so that `foo` does not get copied on return.

Now suppose I want to return two different values:

```
auto foo() {
    Foo foo { /* ... */ };
    Bar bar { /* ... */ };
    do_stuff(foo, bar);
    return std::make_tuple(foo, bar);
}
```

This naive implementation will likely trigger the construction of two copies of each `Foo` and `Bar` ([<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/Grs4TjqWz)).

How should I best modify my code to avoid this copying, without messing up my return type?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it would be to declare your Foo and Bar objects inside the tuple to begin with:

```
auto f() {
    auto ret = std::make_tuple(Foo{...}, Bar{...});
    do_stuff(std::get<0>(ret), std::get<1>(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about moving them into a tuple because they are already in it.

Comment: ...and there are IMHO quite good chances for return value optimization,

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
auto f() {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    do_stuff(foo, bar);
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(foo), std::move(bar));
}
```

will return an `std::tuple<Foo,Bar>` ([<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/qqb8PMbE6)); and will replace the copy construction by move construction ([<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/9dracvnKG)).